# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to　...must be an instance of...none given, called in ...のエラー

Tags: php, centos, symfony

**内容**
現在、既存の作成されたWebアプリのsymfonyバージョンを上げる作業をしております。
ブラウザでアプリを表示したところ、エラーが出ました。どのように解決すればいいか教えていただきたいです。
該当の箇所は、下記リンクをもとに、`$request = $this->getRequest()` を消し、preExecute()の中に `Request $request` を追加しました。

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/UPGRADE-3.0.md

**エラーコード**

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Ahi\Sp\PublicBundle\Controller\BaseController::preExecute() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, none given, called in /home/vagrant/Symfony/src/Ahi/Sp/PublicBundle/Listener/PortalListener.php on line 27 and defined
```

**該当のコード**

```
<?php
namespace Ahi\Sp\PublicBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

/**
 * フロントコントローラー。
 */
abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    const MAX_ITEM_COUNT = 4; //コーディネートからアイテム品番を取得する最大数。 (最大で4個取得できる)

    protected $parameters = array();
    protected $response = null;
    protected $cookie   = null;

    public function preExecute(Request $request) {

        $this->cookie = $this->get('public.ahiCookieService');
        // ---------------------------------------
        // 性別　(順番は会員の性別→ポータルトップの性別ボタン→ブランド→ショップ→MEN'S$LADIE'Sのボタン)
        $this->gender = $this->cookie->get('gender');

        //ブランドを取得し、ブランドの性別を上書きする
        $this->brand = null;
        $brandDir = null;
        $brandDirUrlParam = $request->attributes->get('brandDir');
        $brandDirGetParam = $request->query->get('brandDir');
        //以降省略
    }
```

```
　　　//preExecuteを呼び出す処理
     /**                                                                                                                                                                                           　　　* コントローラーの前処理。
    　*                                                                                                                                                                                            　　　* @param FilterControllerEvent $event コントローラーイベントフィルタ
     */ 
 public function preControllerExecute(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
            $_controller = $event->getController();
            if (isset($_controller[0])) {
                $controller = $_controller[0];
                if (method_exists($controller, 'preExecute')) {
                    $controller->preExecute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Requestクラスを定義するコードの全文は以下
https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/3.0/Request.php

**試したこと**
修正した内容をもとに戻したところ、下記のエラーが出ました。

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRequest" of class "Ahi\Sp\PublicBundle\Controller\PortalController".
```

また、下記サイトをもとに `=null` を追加したところ、下記のエラーが出ました。

[PHPの型宣言(タイプヒンティング) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/buntafujikawa/items/675dec8f3f357b23da5e)

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

**バージョン**
CentOS 6.7
composer 1.10
symfony 3.0.9
PHP 5.6.40

Comment: BaseControllerクラスのpreExecute関数を呼び出しているプログラムは、どうなっていますか？　そこには、preExecute関数の引数となる変数に代入しているコードが含まれていると思うので、プログラムを質問に追加して下さい。
プログラムが判らないのでは、どうしようもないですからね。

Comment: @Fumu7 ありがとうございます。関数を呼び出しているプログラムを追記いたしましたので、ご確認ください。

Comment: 追加して頂いたプログラムで、preExecute関数を呼び出すところは" $controller->preExecute();"となっていて、引数が与えられていません。
そのことに対応するエラーは、エラーメッセージの後半の「 none given, called in /home/vagrant/Symfony/src/Ahi/Sp/PublicBundle/Listener/PortalListener.php on line 27」の部分だと思います。
エラーメッセージの前半「Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Ahi\Sp\PublicBundle\Controller\BaseController::preExecute() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request」のほうは、引数が１個ついてたけど型が違う(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Requestのインスタンスではない)というエラーなので、別の場所にあるコードだと思います。

Comment: @Fumu 7 ご確認ありがとうございます。しかし、preExecute関数を呼び出している箇所をgrepで探しましたが、追加したプログラムしかないようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記の内容に修正したところ、エラーが解決しました。

```
public function preControllerExecute(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $_controller = $event->getController();

        if (isset($_controller[0])) {
            $controller = $_controller[0];
                if (method_exists($controller, 'preExecute')) {
                    $controller->preExecute($request);
                }
        }
        }
    }
```